# C++ class in namespace does not name type

Tags: c++, qt

I have two files player.h and accountTab.h
I need references to player() class from player.h in accountTab.h
and
Ui::accountTab from accountTab.h

In mainwindow.h i declared player() as:

```
class player *user;
```

and it works

In player.h i try to declare Ui::accountTab same like player:

```
class Ui::accountTab *tab;
```

But it doesn't work. It throws error.

> 'accountTab' in namespace 'Ui' does not name a type
>        class Ui::accountTab *tab;

accountTab.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <player.h>

namespace Ui {
class accountTab;
}


class accountTab : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit accountTab(QWidget *parent = 0);
    class player *user;
    ~accountTab();

private slots:
    void on_cleanZoo_clicked();

    void on_collectStars_clicked();

private:
    Ui::accountTab *ui;
};
```

Comment: Delete `class` keyword in variable declaration. And move definition of `accountTab` into namespace `UI`, where it's declarated.

Comment: This isn't C++84, you don't need to have `class` everywhere the same way in C you need to have `struct` everywhere, unless you have a `typedef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you declare a variable, you don't need to use `class` keyword. The correct declaration is:

   ```
   player *user;
   UI::accountTab *tab;
   ```
2. Move definition of `accountTab` class into its namespace, where it's declared:

   ```
   namespace Ui {

       class accountTab : public QMainWindow
       {

       public:
           explicit accountTab(QWidget *parent = 0);
           class player *user;
           ~accountTab();

       private:
           void on_cleanZoo_clicked();

           void on_collectStars_clicked();

       private:
           Ui::accountTab *ui;
       };
   }
   ```
3. Using of `private slots:` and the single word `QObject` doesn't seem to be correct. Maybe it's just a misprint, but you should fix it.

Comment: FYI `private slots` and `Q_OBJECT` are part of the Qt extensions to C++ that help direct its meta-object compiler [MOC], with appropriate macro definitions to make them play nicely when run through the C++ preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the .ui file to ensure that the class in .xml file is accountTab(in general,the name of the class generated by .xml is "Form",if you desinge by Qt designer)

Comment: This can be the cause of this compiler error. It isn't the right answer to this specific question. But did just resolve my issue.